# Send C++ input from terminal in one line

Tags: c++, c, unix, iostream

I have a C++ algorithm which takes in some user input, so roughly something like

```
./sum.out
Enter a: 2
Enter b: 3
Sum is 5
```

on a UNIX shell. What I want to do is automate the process by using another c++ file which sends several `system("./sum.out")` commands but I don't know how to make it also send the parameters, i.e. `a` and `b` in my case. In other words, I want the second file to supply it with the parameters and not the user.

Comment: Please pick C or C++ as a tag. Not both. The most appropriate answer may be different depending which you pick. And does it have to be done via `system`?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it's just the only way I know hot to do it

Comment: There are some more elegant but also slightly more complex ways to do this using `pipe`, `fork`, `exec` and `dup`. If you want something simple can just do `system("echo 2 3 | ./sum.out");`. Note that the string inside `system` can be dynamically generated. By using something like `snprintf` to store a formatted string into a buffer and then pass that buffer to `system`. Or better still (IMHO) is to ditch the C/C++ test program approach altogther and write a shell script to test your program.

Comment: `snprintf` did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a formatted string:

```
char buffer[100];
snprintf(buffer,100,"echo %d %d | ./sum.out",2,3);
system(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [IO redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_01.html):

```
$ ./sum.out < in.txt
```

where `in.txt` is a text file containing input:

```
$ cat in.txt
2
3
```

to redirect stdout from a program `a.out` to stdin of `sum.out`

```
`$ ./input.out | ./sum.out`
```

Comment: I can't really use that because my a's and b's would be different each time I run the code.